# Draw a single bar in <td> with Google Visualization API

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to add a simple bar to visually show a value between 0 and 1 in an HTML table cell. The Formatter option in Google Visualization API is only available for a DataTable and I cannot just inject it into an HTML table cell.

Should I just create a full bar chart for the single value and add it to the cell? Or is there a better solution/

Answer (score 2):

Use a [BarFormatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#barformatter) on the appropriate column of the DataTable.  When drawing your Table visualization, you should see a bar in the cells of that column:

```
// use a BarFormatter on column 2 of the DataTable
var barFormatter = new google.visualization.BarFormat({base: 0, min: 0, max: 1});
barFormatter.format(data, 2);
```

Comment: thank you. but i cannot use a DataTable because the table HTML is generated by code that somebody else maintains and i cannot modify.

Comment: Are you using a Table Visualization, or are you looking for a way to inject a bar into a regular HTML table?

Comment: the latter, inject a bar into a regular HTML table

Comment: Ok, then what you need is to put a `<div>` inside the table cell, and use that div as the container of a [BarChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart).  The chart's configuration options should allow you to make it look correct for your application.